# Matrix; Linear transformations

Tags: matrices, trigonometry

Let $ ( x , y ) $ be the co-ordinates of a point P referred to a set of rectangular axes $OX$, $OY$.
Then its co-ordinates ($x^{'}$,$y^{'}$) referred to $OX^{'}$, $OY^{'}$, obtained by rotating the former axes through an angle $\theta$ are given by

$x^{'}$=$x\cos{\theta}+y\sin{\theta}$

$y^{'}$=$-x\sin{\theta}+y\cos{\theta}$

How do we derive the result for $(x^{'},y^{'})$ from $(x,y)$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A_\theta$ the matrix of the rotation transformation:

$$A_\theta=\left(\begin{matrix}
\cos \theta&-\sin\theta\\
\sin\theta&\cos\theta
\end{matrix}\right)$$
so if $u=(x,y)^T$ and $u'=(x',y')^T$ is the vector obtained by rotating the vector $u$ by an angle $\theta$ then
$$u'=A_\theta \cdot u$$

Answer (score 0):

If $A_\theta$ is the matrix of the rotation transformation:

Then, $$A_\theta=\left(\begin{matrix}
\cos \theta& \sin\theta\\
-\sin\theta &\cos\theta
\end{matrix}\right)$$

$$\left(\begin{matrix}
x^{'}&\\
y^{'}&\end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}
\cos \theta& \sin\theta\\
-\sin\theta &\cos\theta
\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}
x&\\
y&\end{matrix}\right)$$